# How to keep track of the number of iPhone app users?

Tags: iphone, itunes

Is there a way to find out how many users are using a specific iPhone app. I just want to check the numbers of people using my app.

Thanks

Comment: Additional information available in this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461089/how-to-gather-usage-statistics-for-iphone-app/8017202#8017202

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Flurry Analytics. It will let you track users as well as track individual function calls inside your application. You can see how people use your program as well as the number of users and their region of the world.

It knows how to hold information back and send it only when the device is connected to a network as well.

You'll have to rebuild and release and updated version of your App to include any of the analytical tools of course.

-t

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to have a web server back end that keeps track of that.

However, this may not be accurate as you want to make sure that (provided your game is an offline game) the game is still playable even though it may not be able to communicate with your backend system.

Answer (score 0):

There is a number of analytics tools available. [Google analytics](http://googlemobile.blogspot.com/2009/11/introducing-google-analytics-for-mobile.html) as an example. 

Look at [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764974/can-admob-be-used-just-for-iphone-app-statistics-analytics/)

Comment: In that instance, Google Analytics indeed provides such a backend for you. Still need to ensure your pageview mechanism doesn't affect the app's functioning if no Internet connection is available.

Comment: Yes, sure. Google analytics can handle it. Have not tried other frameworks so can't say about them

Comment: I've used Pinch Analytics in the past, which has worked well for me. Google Analytics should work as well. I've never heard of Flurry, though, so I can't compare.

Answer (score 0):

You can also view the number of people who update the software on iTunes Connect.  This can give you a rough estimate of the people who are still interested in your software.